# PHP array from javascript checkboxes, Limit

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I've come across a problem with limit of checked boxes in php array.
it does not display more than 50.
I need to get comma-separated string and when i check more than 50 boxes:

```
320,310,330,318,218,321,313,300,198,316,325,193,298,332,311,329,190,326,212,299,328,214,322,333,315,323,213,335,324,334,290,312,331,336,317,319,314,327,337,302,306,297,305,309,307,308,301,303,304,265,
```

empty after 50th comma. For example if i checked 4 boxes:

```
320,310,330,318
```

max_input_vars set to 2000 in php.ini

code:

```
 if($_REQUEST["smstoadd"])
  {
      $smsto = implode(",",$_REQUEST["smstoadd"]); 
  }
  else
  {
      $smsto = 0;
  }
```

---

```
<?    
$getPeopleSMS= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `cansms` ='1'
     ORDER BY `fullname` ASC");
                        while($getS = mysql_fetch_array($getPeopleSMS))
                        {
                    ?>  
                     <input id="is<?=$getS["id"]?>" name="smstoadd[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$getS["id"]?>"
     />&nbsp;<label><?=$getS["fullname"]?></label><BR>
                    <?
                        }
                    ?>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
                   <?
                   if(strpos($smsto,",")!=0)
                        {
                        
                        $smsto = explode(",",$smsto);
                            foreach($smsto as $valuesm)
                            {
                        ?>
                            $("#is<?=$valuesm?>").attr("checked","checked");
                        <?
                            }
                       
                        }
                        else
                        {
                    ?>
                        $("#is<?=$smsto?>").attr("checked","checked");
                        <?
                        }
                        ?>
                });
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behavior on our three php servers (php5, php7, php7.2). How did you come to the conclusion that the value is clipped? Did you do a direct `print_r($_POST);` to see?

Comment: I don't see this form being submitted via javascript (ajax or otherwise). So is that really part of the question?

Comment: Yes i do direct print_r, and tail of  - [48] => 304 [49] => 265 [50] => )

Comment: Have you really looked close to your html output in the browser inspector, to make sure that all those 50+ checkbox fields are correct? No odd garbage being tossed in by php in any of them, or the like? I still cannot seem to reproduce this other than forcing PHP down to just 49 POST var limit... but then I get an entirely different error which simply halts/wipes all of post.